# C# CefSharp chromeBrowser Trying to simulate keypresses and mouse clicks

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am at a loss after looking at relevant posts and documentation, many others seem to have had similar problems, but none of the existing solutions results in any keypresses actually being recognized by the browser.

All my code is below, just an empty form trying to type in a username/password on a website that currently doesn't have an API but it is coming. So this is just a bandaid fix until their API is fleshed out. Mostly just need to login and send keypresses to the website, but nothing seems to be working.

I have also tried: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/520/simulating-keypress-in-the-right-way-using-inputsimulator-with-csharp-in-winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;


namespace Hydros_tmp_api
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;
        string CurrentAddress = "";

        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            // Initialize cef with the provided settings
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            // Create a browser component
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.coralvuehydros.com/app/#/status");
            // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
            Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            (chromeBrowser).LoadingStateChanged += Browser_FrameLoadEnd;

            chromeBrowser.AddressChanged += Browser_AddressChanged;
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        async void Browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
        { // Jumps in here when the page is fully loaded:
            if (e.IsLoading == false)
            {
                if (CurrentAddress.Contains("login"))
                {
                    timer_login.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Browser_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentAddress = e.Address;
        }

        private void timer_login_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer_login.Enabled = false;
                    chromeBrowser.GetBrowserHost().SetFocus(true);
                    Random rnd = new Random();


                    chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent
                    {
                        WindowsKeyCode = (int)Keys.Tab, // Enter
                        FocusOnEditableField = true,
                        IsSystemKey = false,
                        Type = KeyEventType.KeyDown
                    });

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(20, 120));

                    chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent
                    {
                        WindowsKeyCode = (int)Keys.Tab, // Enter
                        FocusOnEditableField = true,
                        IsSystemKey = false,
                        Type = KeyEventType.KeyUp
                    });

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(20, 120));

                    chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent
                    {
                        WindowsKeyCode = (int)Keys.T, // Enter
                        FocusOnEditableField = true,
                        IsSystemKey = false,
                        Type = KeyEventType.KeyDown
                    });

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(20, 120));

                    chromeBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent
                    {
                        WindowsKeyCode = (int)Keys.T, // Enter
                        FocusOnEditableField = true,
                        IsSystemKey = false,
                        Type = KeyEventType.KeyUp
                    });

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(20, 120));

        }

    }
}
```

Edit: It appears to be a specific oddity with their website that is not accepting simulated input because it works fine on other sites? So idk where to go from here.

Comment: You might want to try different approach. Run fiddler, record what is sent. Repeat in your code with httpwebclent. The code will be simpler, and more stable.

Comment: Due to the way this particular website draws itself using a canvas and such I really do not think it is achievable within a httpwebclient.

Comment: Does the website work if you use the WPF version and use the keyboard and mouse as you normally would? The WPF version uses SendKeyEvent internally to handle all key presses. You can test with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: You can add some logging to https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/87/CefSharp.Wpf/Internals/WpfKeyboardHandler.cs

Comment: The website works fine if I type manually, just not via the programmatic input,. with both the WPF and minimal implimentations

Comment: It really does not matter how it draws itself. In the end it just sends whatewer data from browser to server. That's like an undocumented API

Comment: O, you mean for an API system yes that would work fine, but they do not have their API setup yet. So right now I am just trying to write something to pretend to be a person, login and do what I need to do with keystrokes on the website.

Comment: As it works with the WPF version you can add some logging calls to work out the sequence and parameters required, see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input from memory you'll probably need to send a CHAR message as well, I don't remember the specifics and not near a computer.

Comment: Not for API. After you're done with your keystrokes, it sends the data to the server. You can check what it sends, and do the same. Worked for me like 9 out of 10 times